# Kafka Connect: Topic shows 3x the number of events than expected

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are using Kafka Connect JDBC to sync tables between to databases (Debezium would be perfect for this but is out of the question).

The Sync in general works fine but it seems there are 3x the number of events / messages stored in the topic than expected.

What could be the reason for this?

**Some additional information**

The target database contains the exact number of messages (count of messages in the topics / 3).

Most of the topics are split into 3 partitions (Key is set via SMT, DefaultPartitioner is used).

**JDBC Source Connector**

```
{
  "name": "oracle_source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbdis01.allesklar.de:1521:stg_cdb",
    "connection.user": "****",
    "connection.password": "****",
    "schema.pattern": "BBUCH",
    "topic.prefix": "oracle_",
    "table.whitelist": "cdc_companies, cdc_partners, cdc_categories, cdc_additional_details, cdc_claiming_history, cdc_company_categories, cdc_company_custom_fields, cdc_premium_custom_field_types, cdc_premium_custom_fields, cdc_premiums, cdc, cdc_premium_redirects, intermediate_oz_data, intermediate_oz_mapping",
    "table.types": "VIEW",
    "mode": "timestamp+incrementing",
    "incrementing.column.name": "id",
    "timestamp.column.name": "ts",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.IntegerConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "validate.non.null": false,
    "numeric.mapping": "best_fit",
    "db.timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
    "transforms":"createKey, extractId, dropTimestamp, deleteTransform",
    "transforms.createKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "transforms.createKey.fields": "id",
    "transforms.extractId.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.extractId.field": "id",
    "transforms.dropTimestamp.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
    "transforms.dropTimestamp.blacklist": "ts",
    "transforms.deleteTransform.type": "de.meinestadt.kafka.DeleteTransformation"
  }
}
```

**JDBC Sink Connector**

```
{
  "name": "postgres_sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://writer.branchenbuch.psql.integration.meinestadt.de:5432/branchenbuch",
    "connection.user": "****",
    "connection.password": "****",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.IntegerConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.schemas.enable": true,
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "id",
    "delete.enabled": true,
    "auto.create": true,
    "auto.evolve": true,
    "topics.regex": "oracle_cdc_.*",
    "transforms": "dropPrefix",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.regex": "oracle_cdc_(.*)",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "$1"
  }
}
```

**Strange Topic Count**

[image: Topic Count]

Comment: Why are you using mode timestamp+incrementing why not just timestamp?

Comment: @sun007 Wouldn't just using timestamp result in possibly missing entries?

Comment: Correct - `timestamp+incrementing` is a good option

Comment: So you have (say), 100 messages in the source, 300 in Kafka, and 100 in the target? Is that right? Have you analyse the messages in Kafka to determine if they are genuine duplicates or just changes in state for a given key? If they're duplicates is every single message duplicated evenly?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Yes exactly! The number of messages per topic is pretty big (several millions), so analyzing the problem is not that easy. I will give it a try.

Comment: I can recommend KSQL for this :) You could then run a COUNT…GROUP BY against the data.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your source and sink connector config _in plain text_ please?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I've added the source and sink connector configs.

Comment: Is it all topics that have the duplicates or just some of them?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Somehow it's not all of them :/.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an answer per-se but it's easier to format here than in the comments box.

It's not clear why you'd be getting duplicates. Some possibilities would be:

1. You have more than one instance of the connector running
2. You have on instance of the connector running but have previously run other instances which loaded the same data to the topic
3. Data's coming from multiple tables and being merged into one topic (not possible here based on your config, but if you were using Single Message Transform to modify target-topic name could be a possibility)

In terms of investigation I would suggest:

1. Isolate the problem by splitting the connector into one connector per table.
2. Examine each topic and locate examples of the duplicate messages. See if there is a pattern to which topics have duplicates. KSQL will be useful here:

   ```
   SELECT ROWKEY, COUNT(*) FROM source GROUP BY ROWKEY HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   ```

   I'm guessing at `ROWKEY` (the key of the Kafka message) - you'll know your data and which columns should be unique and can be used to detect duplicates.
3. Once you've found a duplicate message, use kafkacat to examine the duplicate instances. Do they have the exact same Kafka message timestamp?

For more back and forth, StackOverflow isn't such an appropriate platform - I'd recommend heading to http://cnfl.io/slack and the #connect channel.